# Change image code to @2x version for high DPI displays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to detect if a user is using a high DPI display, and if so, change the src of all `.feed-item` divs to the @2x version.

`http://example.com/sJaskz.jpg` e.g. 500 x 500 px

`http://example.com/sJaskz@2x.jpg` 1000 x 1000 px

HTML:

```
<div class="feed-item" style="background-image: url('uniquecode.jpg');"></div>
```

There's 24 different divs on each page with a unique image url, e.g. `dhamMk.jpg, xjsXl.jpg`, etc.

JS:

```
if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
    $(".feed-item").css("background-image","url('uniquecode@2x.jpg')");
}
```

How do I just "append" @2x before the .jpg / .png / .gif? The image codes may not be equal in length either.

So with 2 examples:

```
<div class="feed-item" style="background-image: url('dJdaL.jpg');"></div>

<div class="feed-item" style="background-image: url('KsaiP.jpg');"></div>
```

become (if using high DPI display):

```
<div class="feed-item" style="background-image: url('dJdaL@2x.jpg');"></div>

<div class="feed-item" style="background-image: url('KsaiP@2x.jpg');"></div>
```

Comment: Check this blog post http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/?redirect_from_locale=es

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a javascript script for this that does exactly what you need

[Retina.js](http://imulus.github.io/retinajs/)

No need to reinvent the wheel :)

It checks for high DPI displays as follows:

```
Retina.isRetina = function(){
        var mediaQuery = '(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2), (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)';

        if (root.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
            return true;
        }

        if (root.matchMedia && root.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    };
```

And uses the following to add the suffix, (by default @2x)

```
var regexMatch = /\.[\w\?=]+$/;
function suffixReplace (match) {
        return config.retinaImageSuffix + match;
    }

function RetinaImagePath(path, at_2x_path) {
        this.path = path || '';
        if (typeof at_2x_path !== 'undefined' && at_2x_path !== null) {
            this.at_2x_path = at_2x_path;
            this.perform_check = false;
        } else {
            if (undefined !== document.createElement) {
                var locationObject = document.createElement('a');
                locationObject.href = this.path;
                locationObject.pathname = locationObject.pathname.replace(regexMatch, suffixReplace);
                this.at_2x_path = locationObject.href;
            } else {
                var parts = this.path.split('?');
                parts[0] = parts[0].replace(regexMatch, suffixReplace);
                this.at_2x_path = parts.join('?');
            }
            this.perform_check = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Links to external resources can become dead overtime. This would be a good answer if you include the actual part of the src that does this.

Comment: Does this also work for non-Apple high DPI screens as well (e.g. Windows)?

Comment: @frosty yes it does, it works for all high DPI screens

Comment: Ok, cool! Turns out the code looks pretty complex to do on my own, so this is good